# How to determine the downbeats of a time signature?

Tags: theory, notation, time-signatures, beats

From what I understand of time signatures, the top number indicates the number of beats, except for compound or odd beats. Like 4/4 has 4 crotchet beats, while 6/8 has two groups of 3 quaver beats, so two beats in total(?). Now, it seems to me that listening to upbeats and downbeats is the only way tell the time signature of a song by ear. From what I can tell, in 4/4 time, it goes *one* & two & *three* & four &, and so on, so the beginning of every other beat group would get a downbeat. But in 6/8 time it seems to go *one* two three *one* two three, where the beginning of each beat group gets a downbeat. So does the beginning of each beat get one downbeat, or does every other beat get a downbeat? Or is it inconsistent?

Comment: Beats can be different than pulse. 6/8 has six beats a measure, but you can have *two pulses* in the measure (as you described). Where the pulse is, is determined in context by the music. "Feeling" 6/8 "in 2" is actually often a result of a phenomenon called "hypermeter" which you don't need to remember / worry about. Every beat is a downbeat. Notes that happen between the beats are all "off" or "up" beats. Often "beat" and "pulse" are used interchangeably, but they can also be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly a "pulse" is. Is it a downbeat? Because you just said that every beat is a downbeat. But when listening to 4/4 in quarter notes, it seems like only beats 1 and 3 get a downbeat. I'm confused.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - I thought hypermeter refers to the feel of which measures are emphasized in a phrase (an easy example is the conductor's instructions for the 2nd movement of Beethoven's Symphony No. 9 to conduct "ritmo di quattro battute" or one downbeat every 4 measures).

Comment: @jjmusicnotes's istinction between beat and pulse is nonstandard.  The assertions about downbeat and upbeat are contrary to common usage, in which, for example in a 4/4.measure,, beat 1 is the downbeat and beat 4 is the upbeat.  The "ands" are more likely to be called *off* beats, not upbeats.

Comment: Phoog: I agree referring  to the conducting. But it might be defined differently by amateur guitarists. OP should tell more precisely what instrument he is thinking of.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I'm interested in the application for any instrument, but guitar and drums are what I'm particularly interested in.

Comment: @コナーゲティ "pulse" is what is felt, the musical "heartbeat". "Beat" can *also* be the pulse, but sometimes it is not; sometimes it is separate – as a means of organizing the music visually. Non-classical musicians typically make no distinction between these two because many forms of music are not written down, so there isn't much of a difference. In the example you describe, 1 & 3 are emphasized, so if you feel the "pulse" of the music on 1 & 3, it's going to create a different musical character than if you felt the pulse on every actual downbeat.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - a matter of semantics; more clearly it's combining multiple measures to form a larger "measure"; I was modifying the definition a bit to explain the psychological idea of grouping collections of notes into larger "beats" to give the OP context for 2 pulses in 6/8.

Comment: @phoog - Sorry, but you're incorrect here. Many people equate the two in inappropriate contexts, or even fail to ever make a distinction between them. Your statement "beat 1 is the downbeat...etc" indicates that you're not thinking contextually. The fact that you are unfamiliar with the term "upbeats" also indicates lack of awareness. I presented both in my original comment because both are used. If these and other pieces of information are "nonstandard" for you, perhaps it is you who needs to enlarge their circle of experiences.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - just trailled through four pages of google 'upbeat', to find a description. So it's not that well known. And it states 'an unaccented beat'. Which, depending on the style of music, could be any! Beat *can* be different from pulse, but there's no compunction to be. It could also be the very same. Why the snipe at phoog? 'Be nice'!

Comment: @jjmusicnotes do you have a reference to support your claims?  I have plenty of awareness, yet in half a century of music education and performance I have never encountered the definitions you present.  Instead of maligning my thinking, perhaps you can help me enlarge my circle of experiences.

Comment: @Tim - Odd you had looked through four (!) pages...literally the 2nd item that pops up on my google search; definitions available from Oxford, Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, etc. Off-beats / Upbeats can be accented or unaccented just as downbeats can be. And you're right, just because they (beat and pulse) *can* be different, doesn't mean they always are; this was precisely my point: sometimes they are the same and sometimes they are not. Sniping not intended, but don't appreciate being "corrected" with incorrect information.

Comment: @phoog - see my response to Tim's comment. Also, 50 years of doing a single thing does not a large circle guarantee, but rather a deep one. As comments are not for discussion, this will my my last comment on this subject.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - not continuing with 'discussion' - but have you seen the Harry Connick Jr. Youtube where he subtly changes his rhythm to fit the audience's claps to 2-4 instead of 1-2? Clever!

Comment: @tim - yes, love that video and love his smirk. Saw Kansas a number of years ago, and their opening act played a tuned in 5/4; really enjoyed seeing the confused looks on people's faces when they tried to clap on 2-4

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - playing in pop groups in the '60s, we used to do a couple of numbers in 5/4, one of them starting in 4/4. Always loved watching the dancers trying to cope...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, 'down beat' refers to the first and strongest beat in the bar.  In a very simple bar of 4/4 the first beat (down beat) is the strongest, the third beat would be strong too but not as strong as the first beat, and then beats 2 and 4 are more like off beats (a bit lighter than the other two).  In a 6/8 bar, beats 1 and 4 are the strong beats, therefore 2,3,5 and 6 being lighter.  However, remember that it's all quite subtle.  The down beats shouldn't be over emphasized or the piece would sound clumpy.
Pulse is more to do with the speed of a piece.  But it can also refer to the toe-tapping emphasis you feel when listening to a rhythmic piece.

Comment: If downbeats and upbeats shouldn't be emphasized, what's the point of having time signatures at all?

Comment: I said not to 'over' emphasise them, (for the sake of musicality).

Answer (score 0):

> But in 6/8 time it seems to go **one** two three **one** two three, where the beginning of each beat group gets a downbeat. So does the beginning of each beat get one downbeat, or does every other beat get a downbeat? Or is it inconsistent?

This will depend on the **tempo**:

*In popular use, beat can refer to a variety of related concepts, including pulse, tempo, meter, specific rhythms, and groove.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(music)

6/8 can be felt (heard, conducted and played) quite differently:

In a very slow tempo as a Largo each beat can be felt as a downbeat. A guitarist might play each beat as an arpeggiated downbeat **1 2 3 4 5 6**

Adagio:  A conductor could vary his figures accentuating **1** 2 3 **4** 5 6

Referring to rhythm and style a minuet, English Waltz can be played **1** 3 **4** 6 (playing crotchets downbeat, quavers upbeat).

The same pattern   will fit in a medium tempo like a shuffle rhythm or swing.

In a faster tempo (steady beat, March)  the conductor will give just **1** 4 like a 2/4 time with triplets.
The strumming pattern for the guitar could be  the same as 2/4 (2 downbeats **1 2** respectively 1 4 in 6/8 time, where the second beat will be played less strong or tapped (stopped).

Comment: That was not meant! Thank you for reading, guidot. This must it have been happened when changed the downbeat accentuation in bold letters. I’ve not seen this. We can delete this comments right now.

Comment: The fact that tempo would affect the downbeats seems needlessly convoluted to me. I still don't understand what a "pulse" is as opposed to a beat. What I'm getting from this is that the downbeats are inconsistent, and I don't think I'm interested in memorizing which beats will be downbeats in different tempos. I just want a textbook answer regarding downbeats, and I would like to know if it's possible to tell the time signature of a piece of music by listening.

Answer (score 0):

If pieces had no time signature, players wouldn't have much of a clue how they were to be played, without laboriously going through and analysing first.

So, more often than not, a time signature is written at the beginning. It can be an exact feature, or can give a rough guide to the mapping of the rhythm of a piece.

Theory puts these time signatures into several different types, 4/4 being the most used.

4/4 is based on 4 beats in each bar, so there will be an underlying feel of a count of **1** 2 *3* 4. Here, as in most mainstream music, the first beat of each bar is deemed to be more emphasised than any other. That's the main *pulse*. Some music in 4/4 doesn't even play on that beat 1, but it's felt (by most) nevertheless.

Often in 4/4 there is another 'sub-pulse' found on beat 3 - hemce **1** 2 *3* 4.

6/8 is *compound* time. It's that because there are two distinct feels in it. It can be counted **1** 2 3 *4* 5 6 using the quavers, or, **1** 2 splitting it into larger parts. In slower pieces, the former works better. In faster 6/8s, it's easier to count/feel the latter.

It's not an exact science - it's not even a science at all - and all we try to do is make it clearer for people to understand. (And 6/8 seems to be one that is often misunderstood!).

At the end of the day, it's simpler to compartmentalise music into smaller sections so it's easier to read or even listen to - often yu may tap your foot or clap in time, and where that happens gives a clue as to how we split music into bars. They are simply put there by humans to simplify it. Sometimes it doesn't appear to have worked!

I'm sure at least some of this has already been covered in previous q/a.

Comment: I've searched other posts on the site and didn't find much to my liking. "6/8 is compound time. It's that because there are two distinct feels in it. It can be counted 1 2 3 4 5 6 using the quavers, or, 1 2 splitting it into larger parts. In slower pieces, the former works better. In faster 6/8s, it's easier to count/feel the latter." How would the dotted crotchets work better for faster pieces? Wouldn't larger notes work better for slower pieces?

Comment: It either gets counted 1 2 3 4 5 6 or 1- 2- . There's more time to count all six in slower tempos, not so in quick ones.

Comment: "If pieces had no time signature, players wouldn't have much of a clue how they were to be played, without laboriously going through and analysing first." Depends on the piece, as well as the players. There has been *much* music written and performed that isn't organized using time signatures; it's important not to discount this music.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - I'm certainly not disparaging or discounting that sort of music, but most would agree that it's got to be more difficult to play it in a meaningful way - far simpler if one is told information that I, for one, find very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Certain time signatures don't allow you to guess where the pulse is, and require you to figure it out from the music. 5/4 5/8, 7/4, 7/8 all have variable pulse locations which can potentially change from measure to measure--but hopefully not often because that can be confusing.

[5/4 and 5/8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_tone) can have the pulses **1** 2 **3** 4 5 or **1** 2 3 **4** 5
[7/4 and 7/8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuple_meter) can have the pulses **1** 2 **3** 4 **5** 6 7 or **1** 2 3 **4** 5 **6** 7 or **1** 2 **3** 4 5 **6** 7

Sometimes the composer will mention how the pulse should be felt but otherwise you have to look at how the general flow of the music is written to determine it.